# Spring MVC JSR validator, hibernate Validator not working

Tags: spring-mvc

[pom.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gwd.png)

[UserInput Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6rxB.png)

[Controller with @Valid attri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPMl0.png)

but whenever I hit link , validator not working, geeting 0 errors

please correct me where I did wrong

Thanks in adv!

Comment: You should add your code not image ... You can view other question for demo...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the **version of "hibernate-validator"** dependency in your pom.xml file.
Accoring to the documentation: https://hibernate.org/validator/releases/7.0/

> **Hibernate Validator 7.0** is the reference implementation for **Jakarta
> Bean Validation 3.0**. (which is "**jakarta.validation**")

While the version of "**javax.validation**" is 2.0.1 in tour pom.xml file. The "**javax**." and "**jakarta**." is **not compatible**.

**Solution**:

You need to change either "validation-api" or "hibernate-validator". For example, change version of "hibernate-validator" from **7.0.2.final** to **6.2.0.final** should solve your problem.